# Delete duplicate post with same meta data

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using WordPress. I would like to delete duplicate posts from the `wp_post` table. The condition for determining whether a post is duplicate or not is based on whether two different meta keys have the same meta values.

I came across this query to delete post that have a single meta value being duplicated:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    {$wpdb->posts} p, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = '_email' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
```

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    {$wpdb->posts} p, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = '_email' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value

    AND pm1.meta_key = '_list' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
```

I tried running the following:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    {$wpdb->posts} p, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = '_email' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
    AND p.ID IN (
        SELECT p, pm1
        FROM 
            {$wpdb->posts} p, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
        WHERE 
            p.ID = pm1.post_id
            AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
            AND pm1.meta_key = '_list' 
            AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
            AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
    )
```

but got an error message on MySQL. What am I doing wrong?

Any feedback is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: update your question and show us your error message

Comment: It reads "Table p is specified as twice, both as a target for 'delete' and as a separate source for data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you can't have a meta_key = '_email' AND = '_list'. It could be you mean meta_key = '_email' OR = '_list'. You should not use the old implicit join syntax based on where but use a more readable explicit JOIN syntax:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1 ON p.ID = pm1.post_id 
  AND  ( pm1.meta_key = '_email'  OR  pm1.meta_key = '_list' )
INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 ON pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
   AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value 
      AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key
```

Anyway, in your query you have a wrong sub-query select; try `p.ID` instead of `p, pm1`:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    {$wpdb->posts} p, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = '_email' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
    AND p.ID IN (
        SELECT p.ID 
        FROM 
            {$wpdb->posts} p, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
        WHERE 
            p.ID = pm1.post_id
            AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
            AND pm1.meta_key = '_list' 
            AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
            AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
    )
```

It may also indicate that you cannot delete from tables that you use as select in this case. In this case try force the inner result as a temp table with a nested sub-query:

```
DELETE p, pm1
FROM 
    {$wpdb->posts} p, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
    {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
WHERE 
    p.ID = pm1.post_id
    AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
    AND pm1.meta_key = '_email' 
    AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
    AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
    AND p.ID IN (
      select t.ID from  (
        SELECT p.ID 
        FROM 
            {$wpdb->posts} p, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm1, 
            {$wpdb->postmeta} pm2 
        WHERE 
            p.ID = pm1.post_id
            AND pm1.post_id > pm2.post_id 
            AND pm1.meta_key = '_list' 
            AND pm1.meta_key = pm2.meta_key 
            AND pm1.meta_value = pm2.meta_value
        ) t 
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think this is quite what I need. I want both conditions to be met. I want to delete duplicate posts, where their duplicity is determined if the "_email" key AND the "_list" key are the same for both.

Comment: @HernanVillanueva  . is impossible that the same  row contain both .. (AND  clause)   .. check better your real logic .. or add  a proper sample and the expected result  ..

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining myself well. Let's say I have two posts: one with ID 123, and another one with ID 456. If the "_email" value of 123 == "_email" value of 456, AND the "_list" value of 123 == "_list" value of 456, delete post 456. Does that make sense? Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: update your question and show us the error message you have with you actual query .. and second try add  a data sample  (not expalnation ....not "Let's say' ...  just data... just data sample) e show us the rows you want delete  ..

Comment: Why don't you create a function inside your functions.php file?
On post insertion you can query the DB to see if such conditions are met, if they are then you don't publish the 2nd post and return an error message.

Comment: @Enoch the  question is about a not working sql code  .. not about an algorithm  for solve te problem.,. anyway the sql way is more fast that a server side php loop .. (you need  the query for both the way and then for php the delete .. in sql you have just one query ..

Comment: @Enoch I have over 100,000 rows. Doing a loop would be too expensive. scaisEdge, thank you! The second option works great!

Comment: @HernanVillanueva   thanks  ..and jsut a suggestion  take a look at explicit join sintax  is much clearer